# Extract value of HTML code using TRegex

Tags: regex, delphi

How can get the value part only of this HTML code using TRegex:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticityToken" value="56e8af5e4491c1b18472e9ab0e40570b73222499">
```

I'd like to extract

```
56e8af5e4491c1b18472e9ab0e40570b73222499
```

only.

Comment: FWIW, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 .

Comment: But how can i regex a whole html code and only get the authenticityToken  also ty for the link am looking at it right now

Comment: @Shrekt What makes you think that regex is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the best tool for this but if you want:

```
<input\s(?=[^>]*?name="authenticityToken").*?value="([^"]+)"
```

The value is stored in group 1